# How to copy files inside several folders into another directory

Tags: windows, pdf, cmd.exe

I have 6 CDs with PDF files inside a lot of folders (Like Prep1, Prep2... and so on.)

I need to copy all the PDF files inside folders to my C:\ and then burn them all.

Is there a command in cmd Prompt that I can do that quick and flawlessly?

Comment: Clarify: do you need to keep CD/folder structure (/CD1/Prep1), folder structure (/Prep1), or all the PDFs in the root of CD?

Comment: No I don't need to. I just to have all the .PDF files in my destination folder. Sorry for the lack of info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To loop through all folders and subfolders on drive **D:** and copy `.pdf` files to **C:\myfolder** without subdirectories try this:

```
C:\>for /R D:\ %G IN (*.pdf) DO xcopy "%G" C:\myfolder\
```

To replace existing files without a confirmation prompt use XCOPY /Y

```
C:\>for /R D:\ %G IN (*.pdf) DO xcopy /Y "%G" C:\myfolder\
```

Comment: Beat me to it!  FYI I tested this--works.

Comment: Ok, that... is ... awsome!

Comment: Is it possible to have the /switch to avoid to press Y (Yes) all the time to overwrite the duplicate file?

Comment: @r0ca: yes, it's possible. Use XCOPY /Y option. I've updated my answer

Comment: Awsome! I'll keep this command in mind!